# не могу установить библиотеку PyQt5 (питон версии 3.10.2)

Tags: python, pyqt5

не могу установить PyQt5 на python3.10.2 (другие версии не проверял)
использовал команду

```
pip install pyqt5
```

также использовал

```
pip install pyqt5 --user
```

в первом случае мне выдавало ошибку

```
Collecting pyqt5
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.6-cp36-abi3-win_amd64.whl (6.7 MB)
Collecting PyQt5-sip<13,>=12.8
  Using cached PyQt5_sip-12.9.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (77 kB)
Collecting PyQt5-Qt5>=5.15.2
  Using cached PyQt5_Qt5-5.15.2-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (50.1 MB)
Installing collected packages: PyQt5-Qt5, PyQt5-sip, pyqt5
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Александр\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\Qt5\\bin\\d3dcompiler_47.dll'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

а во втором случае

```
Collecting pyqt5
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.6-cp36-abi3-win_amd64.whl (6.7 MB)
Collecting PyQt5-sip<13,>=12.8
  Using cached PyQt5_sip-12.9.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (77 kB)
Collecting PyQt5-Qt5>=5.15.2
  Using cached PyQt5_Qt5-5.15.2-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (50.1 MB)
Installing collected packages: PyQt5-Qt5, PyQt5-sip, pyqt5
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Александр\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\Qt5\\bin\\d3dcompiler_47.dll'
Check the permissions.
```

запускал в cmd от имени администратора

[image: скрин CMD]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: человеческим языком вроде написано что не хватает прав на каталог

Comment: Видимо устанавливать надо с правами администратора

Comment: @Newman я запускал CMD от имени администраторa.

Comment: Попробуйте поменять права на папку. Да и кириллица в путях - это такое себе... при установке либ когда-нибудь это аукнется

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я нашёл ответ и он заключается в том что библиотеку надо устанавливать через:

```
python -m pip  install <Package Name>
```